# Como agrupar e listar valores repetidos em array?

Tags: php

Como mostrado abaixo, no banco de dados vem uma lista de cadeiras compradas, ligadas a suas respectivas mesas. Como posso listar agrupando as mesas?

```
 [M] Significa => Mesa   [c] Significa  Cadeiras     

 $id2 = 'M1-c1, M1-c2, M1-c3, M1-c4, M2-c1'; // Como vem do banco

  echo M1 // como gostaria 
  echo M2 // como gostaria 

  echo M1  c1,c2,c3 // ou se fosse possível
  echo M2  c1
```

Comment: Já tentou usar explode?

Comment: sim mais não estou sabendo agrupar

Comment: $id2 é um array ou uma string desse jeito ai mesmo?

Comment: Isso é trabalho pro banco de dados. Não faça isso com o PHP. Use pivoteamento (SQL PIVOT TABLE) e você vai conseguir o mesmo resultado de maneira mais elegante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exemplo com arrays:

```
$id2 = 'M1-c1, M1-c2, M1-c3, M1-c4, M2-c1';
$arr = explode(', ', $id2);
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $rs[substr($v, 0, 2)][] = substr($v, 3);
}
// Imprime o array (para teste)
print_r($rs);

/**
Resulta nisso

Array
(
    [M1] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
            [1] => c2
            [2] => c3
            [3] => c4
        )

    [M2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c1
        )

)

*/
```

Para chegar a esse resultado, pode manipular o array final ou mesmo dentro do laço de repetição, ao invés de montar um array, crie uma condicional para concatenar uma string até chegar no resultado que espera.

Se seguirmos com o exemplo acima, a partir do resultado final podemos fazer outro laço de repetição

```
foreach ($rs as $k => $v) {
    echo $k.' '.implode(',', $v);
}

/**
Resultado

M1 c1,c2,c3,c4
M2 c1

*/
```

**Observação:**

O exemplo é meramente didático. É possível reduzir e montar a string diretamente no primeiro laço de repetição `foreach ()`.

**Modelagem de dados**

Quando chega a um problema desse tipo, é bastante óbvio que há problema ou estrutura inadequada na modelagem de dados. Se puder, estruture melhor as tabelas e colunas do banco de dados pois poderá evitar esse tipo de "gambiarra" e outras dificuldades que terá no futuro.

Comment: ta dando um erro aqui  Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

Comment: Provavelmente fez algo errado, pois no exemplo não tem como dar esse erro.

Comment: fiz assim     $id2 = 'M1-c1, M1-c2, M1-c3, M1-c4, M2-c1';
$arr = explode(', ', $id2);
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $rs[substr($v, 0, 2)][] = substr($v, 3);
}

foreach ($rs as $k => $k) {
    echo $k.' '.implode(',', $v);
}

Comment: O devo estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: No seu segundo `foreach()`, troque `foreach ($rs as $k => $k)` por `foreach ($rs as $k => $v)`